# Virginia Woolf's stance on literary canon

Tags: virginia-woolf, a-room-of-ones-own, canon

What was Virginia Woolf's take on literary canon? How does her book [*A Room of One's Own*](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks02/0200791h.html) argue or imply that literary canon should be changed?

Comment: What do you mean by "canon" in this context? The idea that there is an absolute "in-universe truth"?

Comment: @Rand: "Canon" in the sense of "[Western canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_canon)", the collection of works that are considered important within a culture.